# Graphs in Django-Big Data analytics

Tags: javascript, django, graph, analytics, bigdata

Well my question is I want to build a running graph with random inputs,lets say in the range of 1-1000. The graph is kind of like a graph drawn by an ECG, an instrument which records the the heart beats and outputs the result on the screen in the form of a graph. The random values should be generated after a particular time-interval,say 5 secs. Upon arrival of new randomly generated value, the graph should shift left and the new value should be represented on the graph, just like this [ECG](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jx5x6tWKdg). Visit the link.

And to give a more broad and practical view, I am developing a system for Data Analytics where the Data will be analyzed and the results(in the form of graphs) will be shown in the frontend.

A friend of mine, who is good with javascript suggested me that this could be done with js. But, I want it to be done using MVC architecture. So , how would I approach this problem. Preferably how can I model this in Django.

Different suggestions are always welcomed.

Comment: Are you saying you want it updated dynamically? If that's the case, Django alone won't be able to help you.

Comment: So, how can that be approached? Any suggestions? Which tools should I use?

Comment: I agree with your friend. I think JS is your best bet.

Comment: So, any idea how could this be done? I mean, I am a complete newbie to JS. So, can you direct me to something where I can learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be its a little late.

Try http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update. This will surely help you.